# How to get changed value from DatagridView's cell?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I tried to to that as:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();    
}
```

It induces an exception `System.NullReferenceException` always when I edit cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

**There is no error :/ , but to get the changed value you shoud use another Event:**

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        String name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
```

**And every time will be saved changed value in the variable "name" :)**

Comment: Edited value can be save in both event `CellEndEdit` and `CellValidating`. In OP's case there no difference.

Comment: no , in Event CellEndEdit the new value will be saved (after Editing) , And if you insist. Can you tell me how ?